# Why does videosphere show up locally, but not on gh-pages?

Tags: github-pages, aframe, webvr

I have a videosphere that shows up locally, but pushing it to gh-pages, the video doesn't show.

There's no 404 error that the file is not there and I am using git LFS for the mp4 video (it's a 360 video, so quite large).

https://github.com/ybinstock/GreatEscape360

```
<html>

<head>
  <title>Great Escape</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
  <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black-translucent" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,shrink-to-fit=no,user-scalable=no,minimal-ui">

  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.4.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>


<a-scene>
  <a-assets>
    <video id="greatescapevideo" autoplay loop="true" src="video2.mp4"> </video>
    <img id="logo" src="logo.png">
    <img id="slide1" src="slide1.png" >
    <img id="slide2" src="slide2.png" >
    <img id="slide3" src="slide3.png" >
    <img id="slide4" src="slide4.png" >
    <img id="slide5" src="slide5.png" >
  </a-assets>

  <a-camera wasd-controls="enabled: false"> </a-camera>

  <a-videosphere src="#greatescapevideo"></a-videosphere>

  <a-image id="logo" class="logo" src="#logo" position="0 2 -2" rotation="0 0 0"></a-image>
  <a-image id="logo" class="logo" src="#logo" position="1 2 2"  rotation="0 180 0"></a-image>
  <a-image id="logo" class="logo" src="#logo" position="-2 2 0" rotation="0 90 0"></a-image>
  <a-image id="logo" class="logo" src="#logo" position="2 2 0" rotation="0 -90 0"></a-image>

  <a-image id="slide1" class="slide1" src="#slide1" position="0 2 -2" rotation="0 0 0" ></a-image>
  <a-image id="slide1" class="slide1" src="#slide1" position="1 2 2"  rotation="0 180 0" ></a-image>
  <a-image id="slide1" class="slide1" src="#slide1" position="-2 2 0" rotation="0 90 0"></a-image>
  <a-image id="slide1" class="slide1" src="#slide1" position="2 2 0" rotation="0 -90 0"></a-image>

  <a-image id="slide2" class="slide2" src="#slide2" position="0 2 -2" rotation="0 0 0" ></a-image>
  <a-image id="slide2" class="slide2" src="#slide2" position="1 2 2"  rotation="0 180 0" ></a-image>
  <a-image id="slide2" class="slide2" src="#slide2" position="-2 2 0" rotation="0 90 0"></a-image>
  <a-image id="slide2" class="slide2" src="#slide2" position="2 2 0" rotation="0 -90 0" ></a-image>

  <a-image id="slide3" class="slide3" src="#slide3" position="0 2 -2" rotation="0 0 0" visible="false"></a-image>
  <a-image id="slide3" class="slide3" src="#slide3"position="1 2 2"  rotation="0 180 0" visible="false"></a-image>
  <a-image id="slide3" class="slide3" src="#slide3" position="-2 2 0" rotation="0 90 0" visible="false"></a-image>
  <a-image id="slide3" class="slide3" src="#slide3"position="2 2 0" rotation="0 -90 0" visible="false"></a-image>

  <a-image id="slide4" class="slide4" src="#slide4" position="0 2 -2" rotation="0 0 0" visible="false"></a-image>
  <a-image id="slide4" class="slide4" src="#slide4" position="1 2 2"  rotation="0 180 0" visible="false"></a-image>
  <a-image id="slide4" class="slide4" src="#slide4" position="-2 2 0" rotation="0 90 0" visible="false"></a-image>
  <a-image id="slide4" class="slide4" src="#slide4" position="2 2 0" rotation="0 -90 0" visible="false"></a-image>

  <a-image id="slide5" class="slide5" src="#slide5" position="0 2 -2" rotation="0 0 0" visible="false"></a-image>
  <a-image id="slide5" class="slide5" src="#slide5" position="1 2 2"  rotation="0 180 0" visible="false"></a-image>
  <a-image id="slide5" class="slide5" src="#slide5" position="-2 2 0" rotation="0 90 0" visible="false"></a-image>
  <a-image id="slide5" class="slide5" src="#slide5" position="2 2 0" rotation="0 -90 0" visible="false"></a-image>

</a-scene>


</body>
<script src="app.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

The quick answer is don't use github pages for video hosting.

The longer answer is, when I check https://ybinstock.github.io/GreatEscape360/video2.mp4 it returns only 133 bytes which is obviously not correct. It is odd since the file's page in the github GUI does allow you to download the entire file:
https://github.com/ybinstock/GreatEscape360/blob/master/video2.mp4

So we can see the file is successfully placed in your repo but github pages won't serve it. The only solution I can suggest is another third-party file host.

Comment: Only applies if you are storing the file via Git LFS. Didn't see the LFS part before, but yeah rawgit doesn't support that.

Comment: @YoniBinstock you'll want to use a different file host for the video content. Because of the way CORS issues are handled on mobile devices, you may want to host both your project AND the video content on the same host. As an example, I've used this service for almost 10 years for personal projects, just one option among many: https://www.webfaction.com/

Answer (score 1):

You need a CDN in front of GitHub pages if you want to serve consumable media files. Try using rawgit.com

Comment: I tried doing this as well and rawgit returned the same 133 bytes. `version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:d7854440a48f35c2594985e45fb77d90e95ed442d8d22afe933f0b7f6b00a02f
size 79955969`

Perhaps it's an undocumented ban on video hosting by gh-pages?

Comment: Thanks for checking this out. 

What do you suggest I do for next steps?